# Is there a way to tweak Common Lisp dotimes macro so that it does not start from zero but from a different number, such as 1?

Tags: iteration, common-lisp

I am using Emacs, Slime, and SBCL.

The default use of `dotimes` is:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defun my-dotimes (n)
           (dotimes (i n)
             (format t "~s ~%" i)))
```

Which generates:

```lisp
CL-USER> (my-dotimes 10)
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
NIL
```

I wish the function could start counting from one. I can change it with:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defun my-new-dotimes (n)
           (dotimes (i (- n 1))
             (format t "~s ~%" (+ i 1))))
MY-NEW-DOTIMES
CL-USER> (my-new-dotimes 10)
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
NIL
```

But, it does not feel like an elegant solution.

The official [documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dotime.htm) mentions a `declare` possibility. But I am not sure how to use it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "documentation mentions a `declare` possibility" — Where? I don't see it.

Comment: Declarations won't help you, they are here to *e.g.* declare types, optimization policies, etc. The solutions are either writing `(1+ i)` in the body, write a new macro `dotimes+` that would count from 1, use `(loop for i from 1 to ...)` ... `dotimes` and `dolist` are simple macros, if you want more control over iteration, use `do` or `loop` (or write your own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CL-USER 15 > (defmacro dotimes-start ((var n start
                                       &optional (result nil))
                                      &body body)
               `(loop for ,var from ,start
                      repeat ,n
                      do (progn ,@body)
                      finally (return ,result)))
DOTIMES-START

CL-USER 16 > (dotimes-start (i 10 2) (print i))

2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 
11 
NIL

CL-USER 17 > (let ((s 0))
               (dotimes-start (i 10 3 s)
                 (incf s (sin i))))
-1.8761432
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to do that with `dotimes`.  If you want a macro which counts from `1`, either use `loop` or `do` or write one.

Using `do`:

```
(do ((i 1 (1+ i))
    ((> i 10))
  ...)
```